# Failed when query users in workspace via Rally Rest .net api

Tags: .net, rest, rally

I met KeyNotFound exception when i've tried to query the user list in rally rest .net api. The example code  is following:

```
Request query = new Request("User");
query.Workspace = workspaceRef;

var response = api.Query(query);
```

The detail of exception is : "The given key was not present in the dictionary." and its stack traces:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Rally.RestApi.DynamicJsonObject.GetMember(String name)
at Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.Query(Request request)
```

Please advise me the proper way to query a list of users of the workspace.

BTW, is there any way to get a list of users who has permission to access a project in Rally Rest .NET api?

Many thanks for ur helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your syntax looks Ok. Where are you seeing the "...key was not present..." error occur? When accessing the Results collection?

I'm including a code sample below that illustrates querying for users within a Subscription and summarizing their Workspace and Project Permissions. I hope this helps.

```
        // Query for User
        Request userRequest = new Request("user");
        userRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
            {
                "UserName",
                "Subscription",
                "DisplayName",
                "UserPermissions"
            };

        userRequest.Query = new Query("");
        QueryResult queryUserResults = restApi.Query(userRequest);

        String userName;
        String displayName;            
        String mySubscriptionRef;
        String mySubscriptionName;

        // Fetch strings to pull in Subscription and UserPermission metadata
        string[] subscriptionFetch = { "Name", "SubscriptionID", "CreationDate" };
        string[] userPermissionFetch = { "Name", "Role", "Workspace", "Project" };
        string[] workspaceFetch = {"Name", "Description"};

        foreach (var result in queryUserResults.Results)
        {
            userName = result["UserName"];
            displayName = result["DisplayName"];
            var mySubscription = result["Subscription"];
            mySubscriptionRef = mySubscription["_ref"];

            // Query by Workspace Ref.
            var mySubscriptionFetched = restApi.GetByReference(mySubscriptionRef, subscriptionFetch);
            mySubscriptionName = mySubscriptionFetched["Name"];

            Console.WriteLine("Username: " + userName);
            Console.WriteLine("Display Name: " + displayName);
            Console.WriteLine("Subscription: " + mySubscriptionName);

            var myUserPermissions = result["UserPermissions"];

            // Loop through UserPermissions Collection
            foreach (var thisPermission in myUserPermissions)
            {
                // Grab UserPermission ref
                var myUserPermissionRef = thisPermission["_ref"];
                // Query from UserPermission ref
                var myUserPermissionFetched = restApi.GetByReference(myUserPermissionRef, userPermissionFetch);
                // Output project name
                Console.WriteLine("         Role: " + myUserPermissionFetched["Role"]);

                // Try Workspace ref
                try
                {

                    var myWorkspace = myUserPermissionFetched["Workspace"];
                    var myWorkspaceRef = myWorkspace["_ref"];

                    // Query from Workspace ref
                    var myWorkspaceFetched = restApi.GetByReference(myWorkspaceRef, workspaceFetch);

                    // Output Workspace data
                    Console.WriteLine("         Workspace Name:" + myWorkspaceFetched["Name"]);

                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException knfe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key not found: " + "Workspace");
                }

                // Try Project ref
                try
                {

                    var myProject = myUserPermissionFetched["Project"];
                    var myProjectRef = myProject["_ref"];

                    // Query from Workspace ref
                    var myProjectFetched = restApi.GetByReference(myProjectRef, workspaceFetch);

                    // Output Project data
                    Console.WriteLine("         Project Name:" + myProjectFetched["Name"]);
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException knfe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key not found: " + "Workspace");
                }
```

Comment: FYI the try/catch blocks when examining UserPermissions are necessary because by default in the Rally WSAPI, Subscription Administrators have empty UserPermissions

Comment: Thanks @Mark, it works now. It seems that need to assign a Query object to Request.

Comment: Besides, we could use thisPermission["_type"] to determine which type of permission (workspace or project) to handle.