# Unable to query a different workspace

Tags: rally

I was trying to follow this post to query a testcase in a workspace("/workspace/6749437088") that is not the default workspace but the query is not returning that testcase and in fact, not returning anything.  Below is the code I am using. If I do a query with 'not equal' the test cases, I notice that it is returning test cases in the user's default workspace.   I am using C# and using Rally Rest API Runtime v4.0.30319 and ver 1.0.15.0. Any suggestions?   Thanks.

[Inserting test case result using Java Rally Rest API failing when workspace is different from default set on account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632156/inserting-test-case-result-using-java-rally-rest-api-failing-when-workspace-is-d?rq=1)

```
private string  GetRallyObj_Ref(string ObjFormttedId)
   {
       string tcref = string.Empty;
       try
       {
           string reqType = _Helper.GetRallyRequestType(ObjFormttedId.Substring(0, 2).ToLower());
           Request request = new Request(reqType);
           request.Workspace = "/workspace/6749437088";

           request.Fetch = new List<string>()
           {
               //Here other fields can be retrieved
               "Workspace",
               "Name",
               "FormattedID",
               "ObjectID"
           };
           //request.Project = null;
           string test = request.Workspace;

           request.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, ObjFormttedId);

           QueryResult qr = _RallyApi.Query(request);

           string objectid= string.Empty;
           foreach (var rslt in qr.Results)
           {
               objectid = rslt.ObjectID.ToString();
               break;
           }
           tcref = "/"+reqType+"/" + objectid;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
       return tcref;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above seems like it should work.  This may be a defect- I'll look into that.  In the meantime if you are just trying to read a specific object from Rally by Object ID you should be able to do so like this:

```
restApi.GetByReference('/testcase/12345', 
    'Results, 'Verdict', 'Duration' //fetch fields);
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle!  Let me know if it is a defect please.   Thank you for your suggestions also but I would not know the reference # beforehand,  all I know is the test case name(ie, tcxxxx) and also, the issue of the different workspace would still prevail if I use that.

Comment: I set your answer to accepted since you at least helped me look at the issue.  Thanks Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,  I found out the issue.   I was feeding the code a project ref#, not a workspace ref #.  I found out the correct workspace by using pieces of the code in the answer part of this post: [Failed when query users in workspace via Rally Rest .net api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919432/failed-when-query-users-in-workspace-via-rally-rest-net-api?rq=1)   by querying the workspace refs of the username I am using and there I found out the correct workspace ref.  Thanks, Kyle anyway.